# Dynamic item type cast in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to reuse class with dynamic Cast/Model/typedef?(I'm not really sure what should it name)

**ArticleModel.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ArticleModel {
  final int id;
  final String subject;

  ArticleModel(
    this.id,
    this.subject,
  );

  factory ArticleModel.fromJSON(arr) {
    return ArticleModel(
      arr['id'],
      arr['subject'],
    );
  }
}
```

**InfiniteScroll.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';

typedef ItemWidgetBuilder<ItemType> = Widget Function(
  BuildContext context,
  ItemType item,
  int index,
);

class InfiniteScroll<ItemType> extends StatefulWidget {
  const InfiniteScroll({
    Key? key,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    required this.apiPath,
    this.apiBody,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ItemWidgetBuilder<ItemType> itemBuilder;
  final String apiPath;
  final Map<String, dynamic>? apiBody;

  @override
  InfiniteScrollState<ItemType> createState() => InfiniteScrollState();
}

class InfiniteScrollState<ItemType> extends State<InfiniteScroll> {
  final PagingController<int, ItemType> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int page) async {
    try {
      Response resp = await Api().post(widget.apiPath, body: widget.apiBody!);
      dynamic j = json.decode(resp.body);

      List<ItemType>? items =
          List<ItemType>.from(j['data'].map((map) => ItemType.fromJSON(map)));
      final isLastPage = items.length < Constants.paginationItemPerPage;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(items);
      } else {
        _pagingController.appendPage(items, page + 1);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PagedListView<int, ItemType>(
      pagingController: _pagingController,
      builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<ItemType>(
        itemBuilder: (context, item, index) =>
            widget.itemBuilder(context, item, index),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above 2 is my model and InfiniteScroll class that use of infinite_scroll_pagination, but I found that copy-paste the code every time really not ideal, so I try to create another layer of StatefulWidget that can re-use by changing ArticleModel to any other Model

**ArticleListScreen.dart**
here I trying to re-use the InfiniteScroll class, but I got warning/error of

```
class MeArticleListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MeArticleListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MeArticleListScreenState createState() => MeArticleListScreenState();
}

class MeArticleListScreenState extends State<MeArticleListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppTheme.appTheme.defaultAppBar(
        title: 'announcement'.tr(),
      ),
      body: InfiniteScroll<ArticleModel>(
        apiPath: '/article/list',
        itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
          return Text('Demo demo 123');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

above I trying to re-use the class InfiniteScroll, but I'm getting error from the **InfiniteScroll.dart** file

> List? items =
> List.from(j['data'].map((map) => ItemType.fromJSON(map)));

**error below:**

> The method fromJSON isn't defined for the type "Type". Try correcting the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromJSON'

I think one of the workaround is changing the **PagedListView<int, ItemType>** to **PagedListView<int, dynamic>**, remove all the ItemType and cast the item in the itemBuilder from parent?

Comment: `ItemType` is just a type object. It's not an alias for whatever type you want, so you can't use it to call static methods on `ArticleModel` or whatever else you pass in as the type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you can not invoke static methods on generic types. This is because static methods are not inherited, meaning even when you constrain the generic `class A<Generic extends FromJsonAbstract>`, there is no way of knowing which static methods it provides no matter what `FromJsonAbstract` may implement.

There are multiple ways of overcoming this problem; one would be to simply add a from Json property to your widget:

```
class InfiniteScroll<ItemType> extends StatefulWidget {
  const InfiniteScroll({
    Key? key,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    required this.apiPath,
    required this.fromJson,
    this.apiBody,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ItemWidgetBuilder<ItemType> itemBuilder;
  final String apiPath;
  final ItemType Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson;
  final Map<String, dynamic>? apiBody;
```

Now you can specify the conversion method in the parameters:

```
InfiniteScroll<ArticleModel>(
        apiPath: '/article/list',
        fromJson: (json) => ArticalModel.fromJSON(json),
        itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
          return Text('Demo demo 123');
        },
      ),
```